# Find and Replace in email ids to mailto link in thymleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I would like to know email ids in thymleaf template to mailto link
eg : hello@gmail.com to `<a href="mailto:hello@gmail.com"></a>`

It should use regex for finding email IDs.

I have tried with thymleaf inline javascript but unfortuantely not working in outlook.

```
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
    function formatEmails(){
        var content=document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;       
        var regex = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/g
        var matches = [];
        var match = regex.exec(content);
        var formatedContent=content;
        while (match != null) {
            if(matches.indexOf(match[0]) === -1)matches.push(match[0]); 
            match = regex.exec(content);
        }
        matches.forEach(function(email,index){
            formatedContent=formatedContent.split(email).join('<a href="mailto:'+email+'">'+email+'</a>')
        });
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=formatedContent;
   }
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

If there is no direct way to do this, how to make it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what exactly you are asking. You want to replace `me@email.com` with `<a href="mailto:me@email.com">me@email.com</a>` I think? Why don't you do that in the Thymeleaf template itself?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Yes exactly. How to do that in thymleaf?.That was my question actually.

Comment: Is `content` a HTML input where the user can type? Or is it a `<div>` that is rendered by the server? If it is just displaying content, you can use string replacement in your controller in Java.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe  Is there any way to do this in template itself something like find and replace using regex.

Comment: There is `#strings.replace` in Thymeleaf (See https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-b-expression-utility-objects), but that does does not work with regex. See https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/730 for the relevant issue.